# Cannot connect to MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, iis, windows-7

Seems like a beginner question but I can't seem to figure it out ...

I have a fresh Windows 7 x64 / Apache 2.2 / PHP 5.2 / MySQL 5 x64 installation.
Actually I tried both IIS and Apache.

But this PHP Code does not work:

```
<?
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";

$db = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("die");
?>
```

- I can connect OK to the MySQL database using direct command line, using of course the same login/password.
- I can access the MySQL database through the network with still the same login/password.
- PHP is working otherwise (`echo("hello world")` does work).
- The MySQL extension is enabled in php.ini. In fact, if I disable it I get `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`.
- Windows Firewall disabled.
- No error message. It just doesn't return anything. After 600 seconds, it times out:

  ```
      Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in
          C:\Ampache\try.php on line 6
  ```

Any clue?

Comment: I think you are not passing in the last parameter for the database name.

Comment: Can you add a `error mysql_error()` to the end?

Comment: @Jacob : the database name is optionnal. 

@Pekka : I did indeed. But it never passes after the mysql_connect().

Comment: did you try this: `error_reporting( E_ALL );`?

Comment: @Jacob: the 4th parameter to mysql_connect is a boolean for new link, not a database name.

Comment: Hi, maybe it is the environment problem. Say, system path?
I recommend XAMPP on windows, it is deadly easy to run everything withiout a headache :)

Comment: @Jacob : Yes I tried with maximum error reporting : no error but the timeout.    
By the way, I've just answered the question so check it out :-)

Comment: @Michael : I prefer to setup everything manually. It cost one or two headaches but I like the feeling that I understand everything at the end :-)

Comment: Sorry, recently i've only used the mysqli oop api.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wait Wait Wait ... I think I found it ...

RTM they said :-) It's all at `http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-connect.php` :

> Bruce Kirkpatrick - 28-Oct-2009 05:48 :
>   On Windows Vista or above, an entry in the Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts file causes mysql_connect() connections to "localhost" to timeout and never connect.  This happens on php 5.3 and above since it now uses mysql native driver which has changed it connection behavior compared to libmysql.dll in previous versions.  It is not a PHP bug, but definitely a configuration issue for users on new windows systems.
>
> To get around this, you must remove the entry like this:
>   ::1             localhost
>
> and make sure you still have:
>   127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> Also, you could change the code to connect to the ip instead, but that is inconvenient if you have many web sites.
>
> This issue occurs on Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008.

In fact it works with

```
$host = "127.0.0.1";
```

Thanks for your interest !

Comment: I too had this problem on Win7. Spent hours figuring this our for myself when I was testing the 5.3 beta (no documentation back then). -  A regression "bug" in M$s newest systems that breaks most code written for the most popular alternative to ISS/.Net ... shocking, right? xD

Comment: In fact I'm not shocked to see the setting : 
    ::1 localhost
which appears to me as correct ...  

But I'm shocked that :   
 - at end of 2009, PHP/MySQL does not handle yet IPV6  
 - PHP/MySQL just freezes instead of handling better the connexion problem, with a serious error message ...   

What do you think ?

Comment: Just went through the same thing 6 months later.  Wish it had turned up in google a couple of hours earlier in the trouble shooting!

Comment: Had the same problem twice lately (I reinstalled to SSD, but couldnt remember what I did earlier) - and this was it. Thank you!

Comment: Happy that it can be useful to others :-) ... Still feel that PHP/MySQL should handle IPV6 better ...

Answer (score 0):

In case you whant localhost to work, you could edit your hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc., or use another dns

Answer (score 0):

It's simple in win7/vista there's is a localhost bug. If you use you computername instead of "localhost" it should work.

Happy php'ing